# Which Python Gui and libraries should I use?

Tags: python, user-interface, open-source, ide

We intend to make an Open Source Software,wherein we will be parsing XML files and also include an Image Viewer along with other things.As **Python** is easier for developing and also it supports platforms like Linux and windows.Can anyone suggest a **good GUI IDE/builder** that is **free and supports Drag and Drop for RAD**.Also,we intend to make a Good GUI interface(which includes menus and other toolboxes)The Software will also have some **Image Processing capabilities**,so we are planning to incorporate openCV.There are a lot of IDEs/Builders out there,we are not able to decide properly.

Comment: this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling... not a good format for SO.

Comment: I'd beg to differ. there have been rather a few things on SO like 'which book is best for starting Lisp/Compiler/etc/?' Stuff that people google about and SO manages to give a very comprehensive (and correct) answer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's just MY opnion, but some time ago I've made a lot of tests with almost all free GUI designers I found, this includes designer for pyQT, WX and TKinter, and to be honest with you,  I don't like the way they work, or the template they generate or any other issue they have. BUT... at the end I chose the TKInter (normally the people will say this is the worst one and I have to agree, the graphics are not so contemporaneous, but it comes already installed with python), and as a desiner I'm using [PAGE](http://page.sourceforge.net/) (it needs TCL installed to run and its main target is to generate templates also in TCL but you can export to python easily). The big advantage to me in using PAGE was the way it place components into the form (it uses *place* instead of *pack*, and I don't like the limitations pack have). In the same application I used [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) as graphical engine and it worked very well with TKInter's *canvas* component. 
Again, this is MY personal opnion.

Comment: thanks for such a descriptive reply!I will definately look into it.

Answer (score 0):

you should list down the ones that you have come across, so it can help people give you recommendations based on that.

There is pyQT, which should help you accomplish what you want. there is also [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/)

Comment: personally I like wx alot...(glade is the gui builder...but its pretty easy to do with just code)